# Recuperar imagem em disco via callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, java-ee, upload, canvas

Bem, estou desenvolvendo uma funcionalidade que tem como objetivo realizar o upload de uma imagem (essa etapa já foi concretizada) e logo após eu "recuperar" a mesma para realizar a seleção de alguma cor nela (*ColorPicker* com *Canvas*), tal como este [exemplo](http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/158/index.html).

O problema é que eu não sei como recuperar tal imagem que encontra-se em uma pasta em meu servidor para usar com o *colorpicker* mencionado acima.

Por Exemplo:

Estou usando um plugin para upload de imagens chamado DropZone, quando faço o upload da imagem a mesma encontra-se em uma pasta dentro do servidor em disco EX:.

```
/app/joocebox-img/logo/logo_01.jpg
```

Logo, eu queria que no próprio *callback* de sucesso do plugin de upload trouxesse a imagem para que eu apenas incorporasse no *ColorPicker* para que o usuário realizasse a seleção de cor.

Seria possível fazer isso sem criar um "servidor de imagens", como mostra esse [artigo](http://www.thiagovespa.com.br/blog/2011/02/06/seu-proprio-servidor-http-em-java/)?

Estou utilizando JavaEE + Spring MVC

Comment: Você pode utilizar a `File API` para carregar o arquivo em Javascript, já que o usuário já esta selecionando a imagem.

Comment: Hummm @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira vou dar uma lida na documentação. Nunca trabalhei com ela (pelo menos por enquanto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, acabei resolvendo o problema escolhendo um simples [*colorPicker*](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?ALE9mfyN) jquery mesmo. Optei por essa abordagem por falta de tempo no projeto e até mesmo para dar ao usuario uma maior amplitude.